# PHP. How to group values by tags in multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an two-dimension array that contains people **name** and **languages** tags.
The goal is to group all names by **languages** tags

Here is an example of such array:

```
[
 ['name' => 'Ann', 'languages' => ['EN', 'FR']],
 ['name' => 'Bill', 'languages' => ['ES', 'CN']],
 ['name' => 'Jake', 'languages' => ['ES', 'FR']],
]
```

It should be transformed into:

```
[
 'EN' => ['Ann'],
 'FR' => ['Ann', 'Jake'],
 'ES' => ['Bill', 'Jake'],
 'CN' => ['Bill']
]
```

Here is my code that groups by languages.
The first problem is that it adds keys id.
The second I'm not sure if there is any array functions in php that is better to use.

```
function groupByLang(array $array) {
    $result = [];
    foreach ($array as $person) {
        foreach ($person['languages'] as $lang) {
            $result[$lang][] = $person['name'];
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Here is the result

```
[
 'EN' => [0 => 'Ann'],
 'FR' => [0 => 'Ann', 1 => 'Jake'],
 'ES' => [0 => 'Bill', 1 => 'Jake'],
 'CN' => [0 => 'Bill']
]
```

Can anyone help me fix my code? Thanks in advance.

**UPD**
I guess my code is working as it should. However I'm confused of this indexes...
**UPD 2**
An item typo fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code or your result. An array in PHP will always have a key associated with it. And since you didn’t specify a key it will fall back to the default indices (0, 1, 2...).

Comment: Yes, you are right! By the way, can I rewrite my code using some build in functions?

Comment: No, your code is correct and legible. No need to change it. If this answer is correct please mark it as accepted.